# Putting results of groupby() back into a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

This groupby() script:

```
df.groupby(['period', 'tier']).type.value_counts()/df.groupby(['period']).period_days.unique()
```

produces this object:

```
   period              tier      type        
first_period_1of2   100-999_cr      tup    [35]
                    1000-1999_cr    tup    [34]
                    2000-2999_cr    tup    [18]
                    3000-5000_cr    tup    [17]
first_period_2of2   100-999_cr      tup    [38]
                    1000-1999_cr    tup    [45]
                    2000-2999_cr    tup    [17]
                    3000-5000_cr    tup    [14]
second_period_1of2  300-999_cr      tup    [35]
                    1000-1999_cr    tup    [46]
                    2000-2999_cr    tup    [18]
                    3000-5000_cr    tup    [25]
second_period_2of2  300-999_cr      tup    [32]
                    1000-1999_cr    tup    [43]
                    2000-2999_cr    tup    [7]
                    3000-5000_cr    tup    [56]
dtype: object
```

I would like to apply the results of the groupby() script ([35],[34],[18]...) back to the original dataframe, in a new column, assigned to the rows where the groupby() conditions are met.

```
df.shape
(22588, 17)
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample of `df` ?

Comment: use `.transform` to broadcast groupby operations to your original dataframe